# Displaying different images with raspberry in Python using PIR sensor

Tags: python, image, display, sensors

sorry in advance for any dumb mistakes, I'm a very beginner programmer and am trying to help my friend with his project (he doesn't know how to code).

We are trying to make the program display one picture or the other, depending on the reading on the PIR sensor. If the reading is LOW, image A is shown. If the reading is HIGH, image B is shown. For this, we are using the pygame library and the display function.

The issue is: we cannot make the program alternate between pictures.

At first we were using the PIL library, but we found that it lacked a way to close the image windows in a simple manner, and the program kept creating new windows everytime the sensor did a reading.

So we opted for the pygame, as it has an option to exit the display function. At our first attempt, the program would only read the first if, that is, the LOW input. So I modified it as a way to try and make that every time the sensor changed readings (from LOW to HIGH and vice versa) it would first close the display function and immediately open again. What actually happened was that the images kept flashing on the screen because it kept closing and opening.

What we want is that when the sensor reads the input, the desired image is shown and stays on the screen (fullscreen) with a single window, and if the sensor detects a different input, that previews image is closed and the other one is open.

Below is the code [note that my friend initially used a simple PIR sensor + LED code he found online and we adapted it to rather than light the LED, show the pictures]

```
import pygame

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN)        
pygame.init()
while True:
  i=GPIO.input(16)

   if i==0
    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.display.init()
    img1 = pygame.image.load('image1.jpg')

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))

    screen.blit(img1, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.event.clear()

   if i==1
    pygame.display.quit()
    pygame.display.init()
    img2 = pygame.image.load('image2.jpg')

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0))

    screen.blit(img2, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.event.clear()
```